# css background image only on the edges

Tags: html, css, background-image

I am using a background image on my [www.hardcoreleague.info](http://www.hardcoreleague.info) site. Is there a way to have the background only on the left and right edges and within the content of the site, there is a solid background color?

Here is my css for the body:

```
background-image: url('../images/baseballfield.jpg');
background-color: #DEDCDD;
font-size: 14px;
font-family: 'Merriweather', serif;
width: 80%;
margin: 0 auto;
```

Answer (score 3):

use an additional div to wrap all the page content and give a background to it.

**HTML**

```
<body>
  <div id="wrapper">
    <header>....</header>
    etc
  </div>
</body>
```

**CSS**

```
body {
   background-image: url(whatever-image.jpg);
}
#wrapper {
   width: 960px;
   margin: 0 auto;
   background-color: #ffffff;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You may insert to div and set them `background-color`

```
<body>
    <div id="container">
      <div class="leftbg"></div>
      <div class="centerbg"></div>
      <div class="rightbg"></div>
    </div><!-- #container -->
  </body>
```

---

```
.leftbg {
  background-color: #3366CC;
}
.rightbg {
  background-color: #3377CC;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a div then add the image in the background. You resize the image within the div using

```
    background-size: ;
```

tag to resize if you want to.

Here is a link for more reference to backgroud size changes.
https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_background-size.asp